# Combinations Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There is a committee of 18 people, and a board of 5 people will be randomly chosen. What is the probability John, Jane, and Randy will all 3 be on the board of 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 18C5 = 8568 boards.  If 3 particular people are on a board, this leaves 15 people from which to choose the remaining two.  15C2 = 105.  Probability = 105/8568 = .012 rounded.